# Propriedade definida no construtor só retorna valor zero

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, modelagem, propriedade

Criei uma Web API em C# que me retorna uma lista de produtos em JSON. Entretanto, a propriedade `PrecoVenda` sempre é retornada com o valor zero e notei que isso ocorre pois no construtor da classe `Produto`, o `PrecoCusto` também permanece em zero durante a execução do programa, como é possível ver na imagem abaixo.

> [image: PrecoCusto = 0]

- Se eu tenho os valores definidos na `ListaProdutos.cs` (nas propriedades `PrecoCusto`), o valor não deveria estar sendo captado no código acima?
- Como isso poderia ser solucionado?

Segue o código:

**ProdutosController.cs:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebAPI_0527.Models;
using WebAPI_0527.Dados;

namespace WebAPI_0527.Controllers
{
    public class ProdutosController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public List<Produto> GetProdutos()
        {
            return ListaProdutos.GetList();
        }
    }
}
```

**ListaProdutos.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WebAPI_0527.Models;

namespace WebAPI_0527.Dados
{
    public class ListaProdutos
    {
        public static List<Produto> GetList()
        {
            List<Produto> listaProdutos = new List<Produto>()
            {
                new Produto() { Id = 1, Nome = "Arroz", PrecoCusto = 12, Unidade = Produto.TipoDeUnidade.Kg.ToString(), Quantidade = 9 },
                new Produto() { Id = 2, Nome = "Leite", PrecoCusto = 5, Unidade = Produto.TipoDeUnidade.Litro.ToString(), Quantidade = 6 }
            };

            return listaProdutos;
        }
    }
}
```

**Produto.cs**

```
namespace WebAPI_0527.Models
{
    public class Produto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Unidade { get; set; }
        public double Quantidade { get; set; }
        public double PrecoCusto { get; set; }
        public double PrecoVenda { get; set; }

        public Produto()
        {
            PrecoVenda = PrecoCusto + PrecoCusto / 3;
        }

        public enum TipoDeUnidade
        {
            Unidade,
            Litro,
            Balde,
            Par,
            Kg
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como você vai definir um dado que depende de outro se eu outro não foi definido?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem duas maneiras de resolver isto. A primeira é por pra funcionar. É um pequeno detalhe que está errado. A segunda, e é esta que vou mostrar, é aprendendo como realmente se resolve esse problema. Eu resolveria mais ou menos assim (tem como melhorar mais):

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var listaProdutos = ListaProdutos.GetList();
        foreach (var produto in listaProdutos) WriteLine($"{produto.Nome} -> {produto.PrecoVenda:C}");
    }
}

public class ListaProdutos {
    public static List<Produto> GetList() => new List<Produto>() {
            new Produto(id : 1, nome : "Arroz", precoCusto : 12, unidade : Produto.TipoDeUnidade.Kg, quantidade : 9),
            new Produto(2, "Leite", Produto.TipoDeUnidade.Litro, 5, 6)
        };
}

public class Produto {
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public TipoDeUnidade Unidade { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantidade { get; }
    public decimal PrecoCusto { get; set; }
    public decimal PrecoVenda { get => PrecoCusto * (4M / 3M); }
    
    public Produto(int id, string nome, TipoDeUnidade unidade, decimal quantidade, decimal precoCusto) {
        Id = id;
        Nome = nome;
        Unidade = unidade;
        Quantidade = quantidade;
        PrecoCusto = precoCusto;
    }
    
    public enum TipoDeUnidade { Unidade, Litro, Balde, Par, Kg }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/goGSjz). E [no **repl.it**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EM04Q6). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/GetProperty2.cs).

Alguns erros:

- Um objeto deve ser construído em estado válido, em grande parte dos casos não se deve ter um construtor *default*, esse sem parâmetros, você deve ter um construtor que receba todos os dados mínimos para que o objeto esteja em estado válido. Veja [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Foi o que eu fiz.
- O `Id` costuma ser uma propriedade imutável, então não tem porque ter um `set`.
- Deixei o nome e a unidade poder mudar, mas tenho dúvidas se deveria, esse é o problema de exemplos artificiais ou sem definição clara.
- A `Unidade` não deve ser `string` e sim o tipo da própria enumeração. Mesmo que precise disto para colocar em banco de dados ou apresentar visualmente deveria ter outras formas de fazer isto. Para o banco de dados seria melhor fazer um *cast* na própria enumeração e ter uma propriedade para pegar o nome da unidade quando precisar do nome ou pegar o item da enumeração e aplicar o `ToString()` quando precisa.
- Quando trabalhamos com valores monetários o que desejamos exatidão o tipo correto é o `decimal` e não o `double` que tem problemas de arredondamento.
- A propriedade `PrecoDeVenda` me parece que é o que chamamos de virtual, ou seja ela sempre pega um outro valor e retorna,então ela não precisa ter estado. Caso precise ter um estado, porque nem sempre ela deve ser mudado de acordo com o custo ou pode ter um valor personalizado, aí precisa pensar em outra lógica. Não posso falar nada porque não sei a necessidade real.
- Aproveitei para tornar o código mais moderno, legível na minha concepção, e usando a matemática de forma mais otimizada e inteligente.
- Note que a quantidade ficou imutável, porque não acho que ela deveria ser mudada diretamente. Na verdade é comum em orientação a objeto não ter propriedades sendo modificadas diretamente. É mais comum ter um método que faz uma operação específica que tem como efeito colateral a mudança de estado interno. Tem casos que a mudança da propriedade é adequado, mas neste caso acho que um método que estabeleça uma venda ou compra ou outra operação de entrada e saída que deveria ser usada, aí talvez nem deveria estar no construtor, ou deveria estar de uma forma diferente.

Answer (score 2):

> Se eu tenho os valores definidos na ListaProdutos.cs (nas propriedades PrecoCusto), o valor não deveria estar sendo captado no código acima?

A resposta é não mediante ao seu código:

```
new Produto() { 
    Id = 1, 
    Nome = "Arroz", 
    PrecoCusto = 12, 
    Unidade = Produto.TipoDeUnidade.Kg.ToString(), 
    Quantidade = 9 
}
```

porque primeiramente, é instanciado a classe `Produto` e quando passe pelo construtor a propriedade ainda é o seu valor padrão que é 0 e quando entra na  chaves começa a passagem de valores para essa instância da classe `Produto`.

Isso é importante você saber, que primeiramente há a criação da instância e depois a passagem de valor, claro que pode ser criado um construtor com paramentos e fazer o calculo no construtor, mas, eu acho mais lógica quando o valor é um calculo ser feito como no exemplo abaixo:

> Como isso poderia ser solucionado?

Como o valor é calculado se pode colocar diretamente na classe da seguinte forma:

```
public class Produto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Unidade { get; set; }
    public double Quantidade { get; set; }
    public double PrecoCusto { get; set; }      
    public double PrecoVenda
    {
        get 
        {
            return (PrecoCusto + PrecoCusto) / 3;
        }
    }

    public Produto()
    {       
    }

    public enum TipoDeUnidade
    {
        Unidade,
        Litro,
        Balde,
        Par,
        Kg
    }
}
```

[Confira no exemplo OnLine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r2L3HO)

Comment: Ótima explicação, amigo! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Além da forma que o @VirgilioNovic demonstrou, existe outra: a de passagem do preço de custo por *construtor com parâmetro*,

```
public Produto(double precoCusto)
{
    PrecoCusto = precoCusto;
    PrecoVenda = PrecoCusto * (1d + (1d / 3));
}
```

e daí, para usar o novo construtor, em `ListaProdutos.GetList()`, ficaria assim:

```
List<Produto> listaProdutos = new List<Produto>()
{
    new Produto(12.00) { Id = 1, Nome = "Arroz", /*PrecoCusto = 12,*/ ... },
    new Produto(5.00)  { Id = 2, Nome = "Leite", /*PrecoCusto = 5,*/ ... },
};
```

Isto caso `PrecoVenda` nem sempre seja exatamente igual a `PrecoCusto + PrecoCusto / 3`. Nunca se sabe quando o dono da empresa quer aumentar sua margem de lucro, não é mesmo? :P